# Unit test SOQL limit setting up data model

Tags: soql, unit-test, limits, design-patterns

I have run in to this situation where the data model is very complex and since SF doesn't support mocks (e.g., Mockito) there are so many SOQL executions in just setting up the data model (triggers, queries to get formulas, etc.) that the limit is hit.  It is not uncommon to have a traditional web site / application that has a few dozen tables and likewise it is possible to build applications on Force.com that use a few dozen Objects, so I don't see this as unreasonable or a bad design issue.  Also, in production it would never be the case that the entire data model would be populated in one transaction.

I surround the code under test with Test.startTest()/stopTest() calls which separates the setup SOQL limits, but I still hit it.

What we've done is to create a TestUtil class that has a Boolean triggersActive flag that we can set to false and then an areTriggersActive() method that returns !Test.isRunningTest() || triggersActive.  In each possible trigger we call that method and exit out or continue on depending on the result.  Then in the unit test methods we call TestUtils.setTriggersActive(false) on a case by case basis where necessary and where we can get away with not firing trigger(s).  In some test methods we turn it on and off repeatedly.

I like the Idea of something like adding Test.startDataSetup()/stopDataSetup() methods as an enhancement, but barring that our triggerActive approach has "worked", but it is awkward to say the least.

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this and how they handle it?

Idea here: https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000gUkgAAE

Comment: I don't quite follow why your data setup requires you to run lots of queries, insert/updating lots of data i can see, but queries? can you give an example?

Comment: I have had to query for formula fields after updates.  There aren't too many queries like this in the unit test setup, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I second superfell's question regarding queries.

In terms of DML, one of the design patterns that you might consider, for more reasons than just establishing a test environment without hitting limits, is to cache your DML and perform your updates *after* all of your triggers have finished processing.

As your trigger codebase continues to grow - and especially if you install unmanaged packages from the AppExchange (or managed private packages that haven't passed the security review yet) - you will be sharing limits with all trigger code in a given execution context.

Currently, Apex [governor limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) permit up to 10,000 records (per execution context) to be processed as a result of DML operations, regardless of how many DML statements you break this up into. And you only get 150 *total* DML statements, so this is a precious resource. A nice approach to upserting is to use lists of SObjects containing various types of SObjects. For example, the following is possible:

```
List<SObject> so = new List<SObject>();

for(Lead l : leads)
   so.add(l);

for(Contact c : contacts)
   so.add(c);

for(Account a : accounts)
   so.add(a);

for(User u : users)
   so.add(u);

Database.update(so);
```

In this design, all of your trigger code should reside in classes and your triggers pass in an SObject map to be appended to when down in the class code. The trigger code might look like this:

```
Map<Id, SObject> objectsToUpdate = new Map<Id, SObject>();
TriggerClass1.processTrigger(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, objectsToUpdate);
TriggerClass2.processTrigger(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, objectsToUpdate);

if(objectsToUpdate.size() > 0)
   Database.update(objectsToUpdate.values());
```

Aggregating your DML should feel a bit less awkward than implementing a special test-method shutoff valve. But again, this is just for DML - not queries.

Comment: Neat.  I follow how that works in the first snippet, but how does the second snippet work?  The trigger is already being executed due to an update and then Database.update is called again? I do have the triggers call to individual *TriggerHandler classes (e.g., AccountTriggerHandler, etc.), but this looks different.  I suspect with inserts (unit tests use these) it gets a lot more complicated due to FK dependencies and needing the IDs on insert.  You could just group as many as possible object types w/o dependencies in groups of inserts. Feels more complicated for the inserts.

Comment: Oh.  I see how the 2nd code snippet works now.  The objectsToUpdate are the objects that the triggers would each update individually, not the actual objects the triggers are on, of course.  Many of the triggers that we have don't actually update other records, but instead need to perform some complicated validation not possible through validation rules and are just querying the db (in batches of course).

Comment: I see. It might help if you posted an example of some of the complicated validation that involves querying other tables during trigger processing. Perhaps there's some optimization that could help, again for more reasons than just getting your tests to actually execute - namely overall performance.

Comment: On a related note, I highly recommend this new book called Advanced Apex Programming by Dan Appleman: www.advancedapex.com. It covers trigger design patterns and optimization in detail.

Comment: Generically, a parent whose children must have some field that is unique w/in its siblings is the simplest one to understand.  I use Maps of Ids to make it so that I'm not querying the DB for each record, but just in a batch.  Closely related is the one-to-one example from dev501: https://github.com/dseligson/dev501/blob/7b14a6c56d684b8c0aecf764ee480f0102a6ca2c/misc/labfiles/DEV541_ApexLabFiles/Solutions/5-6.SalaryIntegrityTrigger.txt.

Comment: Accepted this answer.  I think that I will still need to use the feature of being able to "turn off/on" the triggers, but these ways of cutting down on SOQL queries are extremely useful and, if designed with from the get go, could help some people avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I like Adams proposed solution and I'd suggest looking there first.

That said, here is another alternative that has worked for me in the past and came about due to the config of various customer orgs. I.e. they had rules in place that I needed to work with.

---

In your test case when you are setting up the data and you don't want certain triggers and/or validation rules firing run as a special user who has a profile and LastName indicating test data is being setup:

```
    // Setting the Profile to one that contains 'Administrator' will bypass certain 
    // validation rules that check CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Administrator")
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

    // Setting the Users LastName to a known value that
    // can be tested with UserInfo.getName()
    string label = System.Label.TestUser;

    string rand = String.valueOf(Math.rint(Math.random() * 10000)); 

    User u = new User(Alias='testUser', Email='test@example.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName=label, LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testUser' + rand + '@example.com');

    System.runAs(u) {
    // Set up test data here where Triggers and/or validation rules shouldn't fire.
    }
```

In validation rules that you don't want to run during test data set up check for:

```
CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Administrator")
```

At the start of triggers:

```
if(Test.isRunningTest() && UserInfo.getName() == Label.TestUser) {
    System.debug('UserInfo.getName: ' + UserInfo.getName() + ' Label.TestUser: ' + Label.TestUser + ' Trigger bypassed');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Nice: Math.rint(Math.random() * 10000)

Comment: @Adam It seems like a convoluted way to generate a random integer between 0 and 10000. But it is the best I could come up with. Suggestions welcome :)

Comment: Although I'm not sure that you really even needed a random number in your example, your method of getting one seems relatively straightforward. I haven't played with Crypto.getRandomInteger, but it might be worth looking at.